# How to suppress the Click event in extended Button control?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I have a custom button in my Windows Phone application. The button overrides the `OnClick` method to prevent a regular click routine:

```
protected override void OnClick()
{
    if(ProgressBar != null
        && DelayDuration.HasValue
        && DelayDuration.Value.HasTimeSpan
        && DelayDuration.Value.TimeSpan > TimeSpan.Zero)
    {
        // Suppress the default click action
        return;
    }

    base.OnClick();
}
```

Now I need to convert my app to the Windows Store one. But the `Button` class doesn't have the `OnClick` method! How can I extend `Button` behavior from the derived control?

Answer (score 1):

There is Click event for Button. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.primitives.buttonbase.click.aspx

You can override button's OnTap method in Windows Phone or Windows Store application

```
protected virtual void OnTapped(
  TappedRoutedEventArgs e
)
```

and set `e.Handled = true` if you want to prevent event tunneling.

> For all practical purposes, the Tap and Click events are equivalent
>   for a Button.
>
> The Click event was originally defined in Silverlight for desktop
>   Windows and it is only defined for the Button control (and derivatives
>   such as HyperlinkButton). You can think of the Click event as the
>   "traditional" way to handle a Button press.
>
> The Tap event was added to the framework in Windows Phone 7.1 (Mango).
>   Tap is defined in the UIElement class, which is the parent of many
>   types of controls. You can handle a Tap event in a TextBlock, Image,
>   and many other controls. Button is subclassed from UIElement as well,
>   and thus can also receive Tap events. It is redundant that a Button
>   can receive both Tap and Click events.

Comment: Unfortunately a Tap is not a Click